# Fetching database date in a trimmed format in groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

My Groovy Script output of a ("select trunc(sysdate) from dual") results in the following string when printed
Fri Nov 08 19:21:51 IST 2019:INFO:[{TRUNC(SYSDATE)=2019-11-08 00:00:00.0}]

I want to extract just the date from the above output, i.e. "2019-11-08" (without quotes)

Let me know the SubString or Trim function which can be used here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by `select trunc(sysdate) from dual` I assume you are using oracle database

1. you can format date on the level of database

```sql
def dateFormatted = sql.firstRow("select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') as DT from dual").DT
```

2. or you can format date on the level of groovy

```groovy
def dateFormatted = sql.firstRow("select sysdate as DT from dual").DT.format('yyyy-MM-dd')
```